# Resharper extract interface from object passed to method

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

I have a question if Resharper can help me with below problem.

Let's say there is a class with many properties inside:

```
 public class TestClass {
      public string variableA {get; set;}
      public string variableB {get; set;}
      public int variableC {get; set;}
 }
```

then somewhere else we have a method that uses TestClass object

```
 public void TestMethod(TestClass classInstance) {
      classInstance.variableA = 'new value';
      classInstance.variableC = 1;
 }
```

of course this example is much simplified to the one I have, but I want somehow to extract interface that will have only

```
variableA
variableC
```

because then I want to pass it as a parameter to TestMethod. Can ReSharper do it automatically?

Answer (score 1):

- Right click the class
- Select Refactor -> Extract -> Extract interface.

It takes you to [extract interface window](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/extractinterface.html), in which you can select all the properties you want to extract it to a new interface.

In visual studio keyboard scheme shortcut happens to be <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> or select "Extract interface".

Once this refactoring is done, it is simply the matter of changing the method's formal parameter to use your interface as opposed to the concrete type.

Comment: I saw that of course, but this extract interface window does not select all variables from that object that are used within method. This is my concern - if it can be automatically selected, as number of properties which are used are not so small and I want to perform this operation in many places.

Comment: So, in other words, no, it can't do it automatically.

Comment: @Konrad This is the best you can get AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I did what I wanted and I want to share solution, or maybe better say small workaround.

- first what I did was to create an interface that contained all properties from the TestClass.
- I changed method signature to get this interface instead of class itself.
- I turned on wide analysis in R# and checked which properties are not used and removed them from the interface.

Maybe someone will need this in future when refactoring. Anyway - thanks for your help!